# Decrypt qr code using PHP

Tags: php, encryption, qr-code

Am working on a project where the data stored in the qrCode must be encrypted for security reasons,

so i have encrypted the data ( which plain text ) using openssl

I have saved the QrCode image on the local directory (public/images)

now in order to scan the content of the image i have used the Zxing library,

i have succefully gotten the encrypted text ,now i need to decode it.

this the " decrypting code " :

```
    $secretKey = "glop";
    $iv = random_bytes(16);

    $qrcode = new QrReader('images/qr/sb.png');

    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($qrcode->text(), "AES-128-CBC", $secretKey,0,$iv);
    dd($decrypted); //return decoded text from QR Code
```

by the way the dump function is echoing " False "

what is it that i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When decryption CBC  mode the IV must be the same IV that was used for encryption.

The IV needs to be random for each encryption, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.